# Permission denied while accessing /proc/<pid>/exe

Tags: linux, unix, filesystems

I am having trouble accessing the file in /proc filesystem
My process once started writes in a log file .My process was stopped and when i checked the logfile to see where it encountered the problem and found "permission denied".
it goes to the /proc directory ,fetches PID via getPID() and fires open() using O_RDONLY to read `/proc/<pid>/exe`
but after firing i get an error "Permission denied".
I did some research and found that kernel enforces some restrictions while accessing certain files in/proc ,but i have 20 process all accessing the same `/proc/<pid>/exe` ,but only one facing this problem ..

```
CHAR fn[100];
159     CHAR args[500];
160     CHAR ProgName[50];
161     CHAR *arr[6];
162     CHAR *buf;
163         CHAR ProcessId[10];
164         static int count_try = 0;
165
166
167         memset(fn,0,100);
168         memset(ProcessId,0,10);
169         sprintf (ProcessId,"%d",Pid);
170     strcpy(fn, "/proc/");
171     strcat(fn, ProcessId);
172     //strcat(fn, "/elf_prpsinfo");
173     strcat(fn, "/exe");
174
175     if ((psp = open(fn, O_RDONLY)) == -1)
176     {
177     perror("GetProgName:ps open::");
178     exit(ERROR);
179     }
```

Comment: Do you have read permission on that file?

Comment: to my knowledge that exe file is a soft link and it's created by kernel when a process is started.so it's being created for every other process in my application but facing issue with only one process and it stopped after firing open()

Comment: And do you have read permission on this binary where the symlink points to?

Comment: yes,rwx all ,for all other processes as well

Comment: it's not something that's happening for the first time,i mean it has been working properly in production for several months ,same proedure,it was yesterday only when the process stopped and i found it was giving this error.

Comment: i edited with my code fragment